# Exclude sub-directory in gulp.watch

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I would like to watch all files deeply nested within templates but exclude any folder after build.

So **exclude** directories like:

- ./templates/foo/build/**/*
- ./templates/bar/build/**/*

But **include** directories and files like:

- ./templates/foo/template.html
- ./templates/foo/css/**/*
- ./templates/bar/template.html
- ./templates/bar/css/**/*

Currently I am having success itemizing the sub-sub-folder names and sub-sub-filetypes

```
gulp.watch(['templates/*/*.html','templates/*/*.js',
            'templates/*/*.json','templates/*/css/**/*',
            'templates/*/js/**/*'], ['build_templates']);
```

But I would really like to be able to stop updating the expression every time I add specific sub-sub-folders or sub-sub-filetypes.  How can include everything except?

Answer (score 23):

I think that you could try to do exclude the `build` sub directories with the `!` sign.

Think of something like this, adapt it to fits your needs :

```
gulp.watch([
 'templates/**/*',
 '!templates/*/{build,build/**}'
], ['build_templates'])
```

You could also have a look to [Gulp Ignore](https://github.com/robrich/gulp-ignore).

Comment: I wasn't able get this working.  I did find https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-grep-stream

Comment: @SachinGorade wrong, you don't need the plugin to negate glob patterns.

Comment: @Aperçu It didn't work when I tried it without installing gulp ignore.

Comment: for future reader, the negate glob pattern should be placed on the last index, the order may affect the result

Answer (score 7):

I know this is old, but you should exclude the folder *and* everything inside the folder aswell, excluding the folder alone doesnt work.

```
gulp.watch(['templates/**/*','!templates/{foo, bar}/build/**/*'], ['build_templates']);
```